# InvalidCastException in converter

Tags: c#, converters, ivalueconverter, .net

This is my class that implements IValueConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Priority))]
public class PriorityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Priority) (int) value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It seems that this line of code throws an InvalidCastException:

```
return (Priority) (int) value;
```

(Priority being an enum) I put a breakpoint at the start of the method and the value of "value" is int:4 so I have no idea why this exception is being thrown.
Here are resources (where app_data="clr-namespace:AssignmentOrganizer.App_Data"):

```
<app_data:PriorityConverter x:Key="PriorityConverter" />
<app_data:KindConverter x:Key="KindConverter" />
```

Here is the implementation:

```
<gridview:GridViewDataColumn Header="Priority" Width="100" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Priority, Converter={StaticResource PriorityConverter}}" />
<gridview:GridViewDataColumn Header="Kind" Width="100" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Kind, Converter={StaticResource KindConverter}}" />
```

Comment: We need more information about this Priority class...

Comment: Check that value is definitely an int -- not an `int?` or a long or a short or whatever.  Could you do a Debug.WriteLine(value.GetType().Name) and let us know what it prints?

Comment: RCIX, Priority is a enum with small values (0-4). Itowlson, in the debugger it says "value = 4" when I hover object value.

Comment: Mohit: hovering in the debugger isn't always fully informative.  What happens if you print value.GetType().Name?  (You can do this in the Immediate window while stopped in the debugger.)

Comment: What's the definition of the Priority property on your binding source class?

Comment: itowlson, the debug was "Byte"! So I changed the int cast to byte and it worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: Excellent!  I've taken the liberty of posting the "check the data type" tip as an answer for the benefit of other people who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to the question, this occurs because what is actually being passed to your value converter is a Byte rather than an Int32.  Unboxing casts must always be to the exact type; to determine that exact type, it's worth checking value.GetType().Name using Debug.WriteLine or the Immediate window.